# SVG blur filter has hard borders

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I have this code in which I want to add a `feGaussianBlur` to a `<rect/>` element:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1000" height="1000">
    <defs>
        <filter id="f">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="20"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <rect x="100" y="100" height="200" width="180" fill="green" filter="url(#f)"/>
</svg>
```

The output is rendered like this:
[image]

As you can see, that the sides are not softened. The sides have a hard border.
But, when I decrease the value of the `stdDeviation`, it works well. Here is the output if the value of `stdDeviation` is set to 10:

[image]

Why is it not working properly with a value greater than 10? And what can I do to achieve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Expand the filter region

`x="-20%" y="-20%" width="150%" height="150%"`

See [Filter effects region](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html#FilterElementFilterUnitsAttribute)

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1000" height="1000">
    <defs>
        <filter id="f" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="150%" height="150%">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="20"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <rect x="100" y="100" height="200" width="180" fill="green" filter="url(#f)"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using this on the web, you can solve this with a single line of CSS:

```
svg { overflow: visible; }
```

This will allow the SVG to bleed out beyond the edge of the element.